# XSLT - Moving child element above parent element

Tags: xml, xslt

My Input XML is like that,

```
<figure id="c001_f001" counter="yes">
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f001.jpg"/>
<legend><para><emph type="bold">Fig. 1-1</emph>Hypertrophic scar.</para></legend>
</subfigure>
</figure>
......
......
<figure id="c001_f002" counter="yes">    
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f002a.jpg"/>
</subfigure>
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f002b.jpg"/>
<legend><para><emph type="bold">Fig. 1-2</emph>Keloid scar.</para></legend>
</subfigure>
</figure>
```

Output Should be,

```
<figure id="c001_f001" counter="yes">
<legend><para><emph type="bold">Fig. 1-1</emph>Hypertrophic scar.</para></legend>
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f001.jpg"/>
</subfigure>
</figure>.......  
<figure id="c001_f002" counter="yes">    
<legend><para><emph type="bold">Fig. 1-2</emph>Keloid scar.</para></legend>
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f002a.jpg"/>
</subfigure>
<subfigure>
<graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781626237896_c001_f002b.jpg"/>
</subfigure>
</figure>
```

XSLT has been wrote as,

```
<xsl:template match="subfigure">
<xsl:copy-of select="legend"/>
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() except legend"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

While using above xslt "legend" elements is appearing properly for 1st instance. For 2nd instance it's appearing between 2 "subfigure" elements. However, "legend" elements should be appear under  elements. Could you please guide us to correct this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `<legend>` needs to be made a child of `<figure>` which can be done by the following template.

```
<xsl:template match="figure">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="subfigure/legend" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And `<legend>` needs to be removed from `<subfigure>` which can be done by

```
<xsl:template match="subfigure">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::legend)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```